# Core Data model - entities and inverses

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, core-data

I'm new to Core Data and I'm trying to implement it into my existing project. Here is my model:

[image]

Now, there's some things that don't make sense to me, likely because I haven't modelled it correctly.

CMAJournal is my top level object with an ordered set of CMAEntry objects and an ordered set of CMAUserDefine objects.

**Here's my problem:**

Each CMAUserDefine object has an ordered set of objects. For example, the "Baits" CMAUserDefine will have an ordered set of CMABait objects, the "Species" CMAUserDefine will have an ordered set of CMASpecies objects, etc.

Each CMAEntry object has attributes like baitUsed, fishSpecies, etc. that point to an object in the respective CMAUserDefine object. This is so if changes are made, each CMAEntry that references that object is also changed.

Now, from what I've read I should have inverses for each of my relationships.  This doesn't make sense in my model.  For example, I could have 5 CMAEntry objects whose baitUsed property points to the same CMABait object.  Which CMAEntry does the CMABait's entry property point to if there are 5 CMAEntry objects that reference that CMABait? I don't think it should point to anything.

What I want is for all CMAUserDefine objects (i.e. all CMABait, CMASpecies, CMALocation, etc. objects) to be stored in the CMAJournal userDefines set, and have those objects be referenced in each CMAEntry.

I originally had this working great with NSArchiving, but the archive file size was MASSIVE. I mean, 18+ MB for 16 or so entries (which included about 20 images).  And from what I've read, Core Data is something I should learn anyway.

**So I'm wondering, is my model wrong? Did I take the wrong approach? Is there a more efficient way of using NSArchiver that will better fit my needs?**

I hope that makes sense. Please let me know if I need to explain it better.

Thanks!

E: What lead me to this question is getting a bunch of "Dangling reference to an invalid object." = "" errors when trying to save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A. Some Basics

Core Data needs a inverse relationship to model the relationship. To make a long story short:

In an object graph as modeled by Core Data a reference semantically points from the source object to a destination object. Therefore you use a single reference as `CMASpecies`'s `fishSpecies` to model a to-one relationship and a collection as `NSSet` to model a to-many relationship. You do not care about the type of the inverse relationship. In many cases you do not have one at all.

In a relational data base relationships are modeled differently: If you have a 1:N (one-to-many) relationship the relationship is stored on the destination side. The reason for this is, that in a rDB every entity has a fixed size and therefore cannot reference a variable number of destinations. If you have a many-to-many relationship (N:M), a additional table is needed.

As you can see, in an object graph the types of relationships are to-one and to-many only depending on the source, while in rDB the types of relationships are one-to-one, one-to-many, many-to-many depending on both source and destination.

To select the right kind of rDB modeling Core Data wants to know the type of the inverse relationship.

```
Type Object graph Inverse    | rDB
1:1  to-one id    to-one id  | source or destination attribute
1:N  collection   to-one id  | destination attribute
N:M  collection   collection | additional table with two attributes
```

B. To your Q

In your case, if a `CMAEntry` object refers exactly one `CMASpecies` object, but a `CMASpecies` object can be referred by many `CMAEntry` objects, this simply means that the inverse relationship is a to-many relationship.

Yes, it is strange for a OOP developer to have such inverse relationships. For a SQL developer, it is the usual case. Developing an ORM (object relational mapper) this is one of the problems. (I know that, because I'm doing that for Objective-Cloud right now. But I did if different, more the OOP's point of view.) Every solution is a kind of unusual for one side. Somebody called ORM the "vietnam of software development".

To have a more simple example: Modeling a sports league you will find yourself having a entity `Match` with the properties `homeTeam` and `guestTeam`. You want to have an inverse relationship, no not `homeMatches` and `guestMatches`, but simply `matches`. This is obviously no inverse. Simply add inverse relationship, if Core Data wants and don't care about it.